# Android O background execution limits not fully applied with bounded and started service

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, android-8.0-oreo

My sample app uses `targetSdkVersion 26`.

I have a simple service, which is both started and bounded with the following code snippet:

```
val intent = BoundServiceTest.buildIntent(applicationContext)
applicationContext.startService(intent)
applicationContext.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
```

Please be aware that I use a global application `Context` for binding, not an `Activity Context`.

The service itself does only imlements some basic logging:

```
class BoundServiceTest : Service() {

  companion object {
    private val TAG = "BoundServiceTest"

    fun buildIntent(context: Context): Intent {
        return Intent(context, BoundServiceTest::class.java)
    }
  }

  private val binder = Binder()

  override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBind")
    return binder
  }

  override fun onUnbind(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
    Log.d(TAG, "onUnbind")
    return super.onUnbind(intent)
  }

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")
  }

  override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: startId = " + startId)
    return START_STICKY
  }

  override fun onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy")
    super.onDestroy()
  }

}
```

Basically I am not sure, if Android O applies the Background execution limits or not, since basically the documentation states ([Background Service Limitations](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html)):

> Bound services are not affected
>
> These rules do not affect bound services in any way. If your app
>   defines a bound service, other components can bind to that service
>   whether or not your app is in the foreground.

But it seems that the OS isn't quite sure as well regarding the Logcat:

```
de.continental.android.androidoservicetest D/BoundServiceTest: onCreate
de.continental.android.androidoservicetest D/BoundServiceTest: onStartCommand: startId = 1
de.continental.android.androidoservicetest D/BoundServiceTest: onBind
? W/ActivityManager: Stopping service due to app idle: u0a141 -1m9s733ms de.continental.android.androidoservicetest/.BoundServiceTest
I/RunningState: Unknown non-service process: de.continental.android.androidoservicetest #14943
I/chatty: uid=1000(system) RunningState:Ba identical 1 line
I/RunningState: Unknown non-service process: de.continental.android.androidoservicetest #14943
```

The `ActivityManager` log message indicates that the service shall be stopped (regardless that it is a bound one), but the OS doesn't stop my service: The log messages for calling `onDestroy` method are not displayed, compared to a simple started Service without binding.

How is this scenario (started and bound service) handled in Android O? Or do I encounter a bug?